# Deploying N amount of meteor apps on a single server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to (sort of) mimic the server setup of the official Meteor **deploy** infrastructure (the *.meteor.com subdomain deployments).

If it's only a handful of **known** meteor apps, I can just run the bundled apps on different ports and use nginx proxying. But how can I accommodate an **arbitrary** number of meteor app deployments on a single server (just like the official one)?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and either use the command line or restart the proxy process on changes.

Comment: looks like i'll be using it

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend HAProxy (or NginX) over node-http-proxy unless you need custom behaviour.

Both HAProxy and NginX perform better than node-http-proxy, and have much lower memory consumption.

Also, node-http-proxy (or just Node.js in general) is terrible at serving over SSL... So, if you go that route, make sure to terminate SSL before Node.js.